# Problems with PIVOT and Joins

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, pivot, left-join

I hope, you can help me
I'm not very high skilled with bigger SQL Queries so I'm not able for about 5 to 6 hours to get the problem :/

**On SQL Server 2008, I get this error's:**

> Column 'pvtMonth.1' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Invalid column name 'j_sumzeit'.
>
> Invalid column name 'j_sumzeit'.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT
    kostenstelle_nr,
    kostenstelle_name,
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mrz,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS Mai,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Okt,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dez,
    SUM ( j_sumzeit ) AS [2011],
    SUM ( vj_sumzeit ) AS [2010],
    ROUND( 100 -  ( ( vj_sumzeit / j_sumzeit ) *100 ) , 0 ) AS [diff]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        dbo.kostenstelle.kostenstelle_nr,
        dbo.kostenstelle.kostenstelle_name,
        SUM ( j_sumzeitpromo ) AS j_sumzeit,
        SUM ( vj_sumzeitpromo ) AS vj_sumzeit,
        MONTH ( j_datum ) AS TMonth
    FROM
        dbo.kostenstelle

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            dbo.def.def_kstnr AS j_kstnr,
            dbo.def.def_datum AS j_datum,
            SUM ( dbo.def.def_zeit ) AS j_sumzeitpromo,
            COUNT ( dbo.def.def_zeit ) AS j_anzahl
        FROM
            dbo.def
        WHERE
            YEAR ( dbo.def.def_datum ) = 2011
            AND dbo.def.def_auknr > 215
        GROUP BY
            dbo.def.def_kstnr,
            dbo.def.def_datum
    ) jahr
    ON j_kstnr = dbo.kostenstelle.kostenstelle_nr

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            dbo.def.def_kstnr AS vj_kstnr,
            dbo.def.def_datum AS vj_datum,
            SUM ( dbo.def.def_zeit ) AS vj_sumzeitpromo,
            COUNT ( dbo.def.def_zeit ) AS vj_anzahl
        FROM
            dbo.def
        WHERE
            YEAR ( dbo.def.def_datum ) = 2010
            AND dbo.def.def_auknr > 215
        GROUP BY
            dbo.def.def_kstnr,
            dbo.def.def_datum
    ) vorjahr
    ON j_kstnr = dbo.kostenstelle.kostenstelle_nr

    GROUP BY 
        dbo.kostenstelle.kostenstelle_nr,
        dbo.kostenstelle.kostenstelle_name,
        MONTH ( j_datum )
) source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(j_sumzeit)
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvtMonth
GROUP BY
    kostenstelle_nr,
    kostenstelle_name
```

**Tables with some example data**

The table structure is very bad but I can't change them because they're from an external company.

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
| def_kstnr | def_zeit | def_datum  | def_auknr |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| 100       | 3.2      | 2011-11-02 | 245       |
| 110       | 2.8      | 2011-02-03 | 265       |
| 120       | 5.4      | 2011-11-04 | 250       |
| 130       | 2.4      | 2011-08-05 | 280       |
| 140       | 4.9      | 2011-09-06 | 300       |
| 150       | 1.5      | 2011-10-07 | 320       |
| 160       | 2.6      | 2011-12-08 | 450       |
|-----------------------------------------------|

|-------------------------------------------------------|
| kostenstelle_id | kostenstelle_nr | kostenstelle_name |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 1               | 245             | KstTst1           |
| 2               | 265             | KstTst1           |
| 3               | 250             | KstTst1           |
| 4               | 280             | KstTst1           |
| 5               | 300             | KstTst1           |
| 6               | 320             | KstTst1           |
| 7               | 450             | KstTst1           |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

**Result should look like this** (numbers can depart from the example data above)

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| def_kstnr | Jan | Feb | Mrz | Apr | Mai | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Okt | Nov | Dez | 2011 | 2010 | diff |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 100       | 8.4 | 3.4 | 2.7 | 9.5 | 3.5 | 7.4 | 3.4 | 1.2 | 7.5 | 3.4 | 3.2 | 7.5 | 61.1 | 47.5 | 22   |
| 110       | 4.4 | 2.8 | 6.5 | 2.5 | 1.4 | 2.4 | 4.4 | 3.7 | 2.4 | 7.7 | 1.7 | 6.4 | 46.3 | 32.2 | 30   |
...
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Thank you very much. If you need more information - i'll give them to you with pleasure :)

Comment: You have a lot of issues in your selects with `GROUP`ing and aggregates.  I'm surprised you didn't get those error codes as well but I think you will once the other issues are taken care of.

Comment: I hope I can find and solve them once I get the error - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to say without seeing initial table structure.
Try inserting "j_sumzeit" column in your SELECT (just after first FROM).

Comment: Hi Pavel Nefyodov! I also get the Error "Invalid column name 'j_sumzeit'.". I edited the post with the table structure and more information. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Desirable result table does not contain info from dbo.kostenstelle.
Why should we have it?